# MVC 5 Not working in IIS 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5

I try to run my ASP.NET MVC5 in  IIS7 but what happen is the website only display the text of my cshtml.

My Configuration:

> GoWireless>Basic Settings>Select(.Net Framework Version: No Manage Console, Pipeline mode: Classic)
>
> GoWireless>Directory Browsing>Enabled

Index.cshtml display only this text

> @model IEnumerable @{ ViewBag.Title = "Active Directory"; } Active
>   Directory
>
> Welcome,@User.Identity.Name.Remove(0,User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\")
>   + 1)!
>
> This is GoWireless active directory searcher, you can use the search
>   box or click one of the employees in the left corner to view the
>   employee details. If you want to search users that only exist in
>   GoWireless\ActiveDirectory and not exist in GW_UTA\ActiveDirectory2
>   you can input and search one of his\her details (SamAccountName,
>   GivenName, Surname, Email or EmployeeNumber) in full format into
>   search-box.
>
> Learn more

_Layout.cshtml display only this text

```
@model IEnumerable
Toggle navigation   Failed to load images
@User.Identity.Name
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
@Html.TextBox("search", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search..." })  
}
@foreach (var item in Model) {
class="active"} href='@Url.Action("Details", "Home", new { id = item.SamAccountName.Replace(".", "_") })'>@item.SamAccountName
ViewBag.count = 1; } @if (ViewBag.count != 1) { EasyAD.EasyAD ad = new EasyAD.EasyAD("dc1.gowireless.net:389", "gowireless\\ldapuser", "abc123!@#"); System.Data.DataTable dt = ad.GetUsers(ViewBag.search); var count = 0; while (count < dt.Rows.Count) { if (dt.Rows[count]["SamAccountName"].ToString() != null && dt.Rows[count]["SamAccountName"].ToString() !="") {
class="active"} href='@Url.Action("Details", "Home", new { id = dt.Rows[count]["SamAccountName"].ToString().Replace(".", "_") })'>@dt.Rows[count]["SamAccountName"]
} else { ViewBag.warning = 1; } count++; } if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0) { ViewBag.count = 0; } }
@RenderBody() @if (ViewBag.warning == 1) {
× Warning! someone is containing the employee @ViewBag.search without SamAccountName, Please check manually the GoWireless\\ActiveDirectory.
} @if (ViewBag.success == 1) {
× Well Done! @ViewBag.search is successfully updated in ga_uta\\activedirectory.
} @if (ViewBag.count == 0) {
× Heads Up! @ViewBag.search is not exist in GW_UTA or GoWireless, maybe you are missing something?
} @if (ViewBag.error == 1) {
Oh Snap!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.

Some Error Accured
}
```

It should be like this

[image]

Comment: http://cdonner.com/mvc-5-on-windows-server-2008iis-7.htm

Comment: @Evgeni Thank you, my problem is done :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Managed Modules**

The bin folder contained all the necessary assemblies for MVC (MVC 5 does not need to be deployed as a prerequisite because it is part of the web site deployment package).

And yet, for some reason, MVC did not rewrite the URL to invoke the correct handlers for my site. So, after more poking around in various Stackoverflow articles and blog posts I had a break-through when I finally came across [this one on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amol/archive/2011/04/14/forms-authentication-for-non-aspx-files.aspx). It explains how to use the IIS Manager’s GUI to explicitly add the UrlRoutingModule to the web.config, even though it showed up as installed for my site:

[image]

After I unchecked the *“Invoke only for requests to ASP.NET applications or managed handlers”* checkbox the Entry Type changed to *Local* (see the screen shot above) and a corresponding section appeared in my web.config. IIS suddenly began to understand `<system.webServer>` section (I still don’t know why), and the site started to render MVC views. [See more at cdonner...](http://cdonner.com/mvc-5-on-windows-server-2008iis-7.htm)

Comment: Man, you saved me! I keep getting 403 error, and other article did not help.